# Why are @ tags not working?

Tags: support, comments, comment-replies

Yesterday I posted a question on the Mathematics Stack exchange.  I received some answers to which I added a comment, trying to apply an @ tag for the user that wrote the answer.  However, when I usually do this, a popup box for auto-completion usually comes up.  This time it didn't, but I continued to type the full name out anyway and posted the comment.  But, the @ tag was removed from the published comment.  This has worked before in the past, why is it not working now?

Additional info:

1. I always put the tag first before writing anything else
2. It has worked in the past
3. I have tried multiple tests with other posts, using other names.  That is, it is persistent and reproducible
4. I have closed down my browser, tried different browsers, indeed different devices!  Same result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably tried to ping the author of that answer. That is superfluous - the author *always* gets notified if somebody posts a comment on his/her answer.

[image]

You can try this with my answer (as long as nobody else comments on it).

Comment: Yes, this makes sense!  I just looked back at all the posts where I have used tags and they have only been present when referring to other commenters, or the poster of the answer when other commenters have already commented.  Thanks!